# Http Get Request Response Session Storage in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs

***How to store Http Get Request Response in session. and you close the browser we need to remove session.***

```js
 // Service Ajax call
        this.getKpiAlertrecords = function(orgKey,orgValue,geoKey,geoValue) {
   var alertUrl ='alert/v1/alerts?orgKey='+ orgKey +'&orgValue=' + orgValue +'&geoKey='+ geoKey +'&geoValue='+ geoValue;
            return utilService.doGetWitHeaders(alertUrl, '', AlertuserInfo, 'SCV').then(success).catch(fail);

            function success(response) {
                return response.data;
            }

            function fail(e) {
                return (e.data);
            }
        };

// Controller 
 e2eservice.getKpiAlertrecords($rootScope.HeirarchyKeyId,$rootScope.HeirarchyId,$rootScope.GeographyKeyId,$rootScope.GeographyBranchId).then(function (result) {
                    if (result.errors) {
                        $rootScope.alretCountLoader=false;
                       
                    }
                    else {
                        $rootScope.alretCountLoader=false;
                        
                        $scope.kpiAlertsdata = result.DISPLAY_ALERT_DETAILS;
                        $scope.kpialertfilterdata = [];
                        angular.forEach($scope.kpiAlertsdata, function (value, key) {
                            
                            if (value.notificationSubject == 'DOS(+)' || value.notificationSubject == 'DOS(-)' || value.notificationSubject == 'E&O' || value.notificationSubject == 'Late Sales Orders' || value.notificationSubject == 'Late Purchase Orders' || value.notificationSubject == 'Demand' || value.notificationSubject == 'Spend' || value.notificationSubject == 'Inventory') {
                                $scope.kpialertfilterdata.push(value);
                            }
                        });
                        $rootScope.whenKpiAlersShow = false;
                        $scope.kpioutfun();
                    }
                });
```

```html
<div class="group-alerts"  ng-repeat="kpialerts in kpialertfilterdata | filter:kpiAlertfilter">
                <div class="kpialerts-top">
                    <div class="kpialerts-date"> {{ kpialerts.clientTimestamp | date:'MM/dd/yy' }} </div>
                    <div class="kpialerts-mystory-btn"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical" aria-hidden="true"></span> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="kpialerts-message" ng-click="kpialerttrigger(kpialerts.notificationSubject)"> {{ kpialerts.notificationSubject }} {{ kpialerts.notificationDetails | limitTo: showtexttoggle}} 


                    <p class="showtexttoggle" ng-class="{'e2e-norecord-space': kpialerts.notificationDetails.length < 60}"> <a ng-hide="showtexttoggle> 60" ng-click="showtexttoggle=1000000">...Show more</a> <a ng-show="showtexttoggle > 60" ng-click="showtexttoggle=59">...Show  less</a> </p>
               
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "in session"? If you just need to store the result so anything in the application can access it, put it in the $rootScope. Since this is an app running in the browser, when you close the browser it's no longer running so your JS variables etc are gone.

Comment: I'm going to another tab and coming back to my page. that time I need to load response from session